# Cannot execute any Rasa command after a fresh installation. IMPORT ERROR

Tags: rasa, rasa-nlu, rasa-core, rasa-x, rasa-sdk

I have tried to intall a Rasa on my computer but ended up with import error. I had older version of Rasa installed on my computer before. But now, when I tried to intall it again it didn´t let me to excute anything from Anaconda to Rasa.
The installation have been done in Anaconda environment.
I have tried to remove the environment and do fresh install and reinstall Anaconda.

Can you please help me to resolve this issue?

Bellow you can find the message which is giving after I try to execute any Rasa command:

```
(RFRasa) C:\Users\LadislavHadáček\Documents\Rasa_Projects\new_rasa_project>rasa -h
```

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Conda\envs\RFRasa\lib\runpy.py", line 192, in _run_module_as_main
return *run_code(code, main_globals, None,
File "C:\Conda\envs\RFRasa\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in *run_code
exec(code, run_globals)
File "C:\Conda\envs\RFRasa\Scripts\rasa.exe_*main**.py", line 4, in 
File "C:\Conda\envs\RFRasa\lib\site-packages\rasa_*main**.py", line 14, in 
from rasa.cli import (
File "C:\Conda\envs\RFRasa\lib\site-packages\rasa\cli\export.py", line 9, in 
import rasa.core.utils
File "C:\Conda\envs\RFRasa\lib\site-packages\rasa\core\utils.py", line 25, in 
from sanic.views import CompositionView
ImportError: cannot import name 'CompositionView' from 'sanic.views' (C:\Conda\envs\RFRasa\lib\site-packages\sanic\views.py)

Answer (score 1):

After a long search I have found the solution.
The error was caused by a wrong verion of Sanic.
After excution of the code below Rasa started to work.

```
pip install sanic==21.9.3
```